# What is the angle-sum in a quadrilateral on the sphere, whose edges are arcs of great circles?

Tags: geometry

Would the sum not change for different quadrilaterals like a triangle with sides that are arcs of great circles?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it would change.

It will be greater than $360^{o}$, but it can vary.

The maximum possible is $1080^{o}$

Comment: Did you get that by attaching to triangles edges?

Comment: Yes, a quadrilateral can be spit into two triangles by constructing the diagonal